# Which type of entity should I use for editable homepage content?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming, panels

I have a set of social media links that I want to display in both the header and the footer, but I don't know where to put this content so that it is easily editable by users.

Right now I am using Panels and Views, but the links would be in the page.tpl.php, which has the header and footer areas.

I am thinking I could make a block, but it looks like you need to know the ID of a block to render it.

Is there a way to add a node, block, content pane, or mini panel and render it inside page.tpl.php?

Comment: Sorry I am being dense here.  Why can't you just assign the block to the proper region in admin/structure/block?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  Rendering a given region twice on the same template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are modules that let you setup "blocks" of service badge/icon widgets for like Twitter, FB, YT, etc.

Look at [Widgets](http://drupal.org/project/widgets), [Social Media](http://drupal.org/project/socialmedia) and [Service Links](http://drupal.org/project/service_links) modules.

I've used Social Media (which relies on Widgets) to put a block of badges on most pages via Context. And also to create other badge collection `tokens` that i've used within Footer blocks and embedded into WYSIWYG entries to show a FB link on the homepage for instance, or a mini-block of service links on a newsletter.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I have a specific set of HTML I want to render in both the header and footer.  I don't think it is important that it is related to social media.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I was able to create a node and assign it to a region.  And now I simply render the region twice on the page.tpl.php.  But now is there a way to not render the region and block wrappers?

Comment: Node are pieces of content (an Ad, a blog post) random HTML fragments arent nodes. Look at like http://drupal.org/sandbox/pwsdotru/1880000 or http://drupal.org/sandbox/znerol/1866918 or the custom token module at http://drupal.org/project/token_custom